# Class does not support aggregation when adding items to a list box?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

I created an excel file in Excel 2010 (Windows 7) that generates a certain number of sheets depending on the input data. I also created a user form that lists all the sheets in a list box.

It works perfect on my computer, all of it. I recently let my coworker use it who is also running Excel 2010 on Windows 7 but her Excel gives a system error when pressing the export button. Any subsequent tries I tried just makes Excel not respond at all and close itself out.

This is the error they are getting:

> System Error &H80040110 (-2147221232). Class does not support aggregation (or class object is remote).

It gives me the option to debug and it takes me to this line of code. ExportForm is the name of the user form, SheetListBox is the name of the list box. All it does is add each sheet to the list box.

```
ExportForm.SheetListBox.AddItem (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name)
```

Like I said, it all works fine on my computer and my other coworkers computer who run the same Excel 2010 and Window 7, but only errors on 1 of my coworkers computer.

As asked, here's the entire piece of code that relates to the PDF Export button that errors. This is the code that generates the list box in the user form.

```
Sub PDFExport()

    'Prevents screen lag and faster code processing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Increments the list if the BOL starts with the right name
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i)
        If InStr(ws.Name, "Bol #") Then
            ExportForm.SheetListBox.AddItem (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name)
        End If
    Next i

    'Selects all the rows by default
    For i = 0 To ExportForm.SheetListBox.ListCount - 1
        ExportForm.SheetListBox.Selected(i) = True
    Next i

    'Position the window before it appears
    ExportForm.StartUpPosition = 0
    ExportForm.Top = Application.Top + 250
    ExportForm.Left = Application.Left + Application.Width - ExportForm.Width - 400
    ExportForm.Show

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `i`, and of `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name` when it crashes?

Comment: Difficult to diagnose, we don't have enough elements but clearly the problem is on that specific computer. I would try a fresh install.

Comment: BTW, are you using ActiveX Controls on that form? (.OCX)

Comment: @YowE3K I'm not sure as I am not near her computer anymore but the list box didn't generate at all, so the error must've occurred during the first loop.

Comment: @A.S.H No ActiveX controls at all; just the regular ones.

Comment: Oh BTW, why those parentheses in the statement? ^-^ I would not be much surprized if omitting them solves the error message.

Comment: Do you have `Option Base 1` but start the i with 0? Alternatively use `Dim oWS As Worksheet : For Each oWS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets : ExportForm.SheetListBox.AddItem oWS.Name : Next`

Comment: Ok those parentheses work most of the time, but basically, they are a syntax error (and more precisely, they have some side effects). You should remove them and see what will happen.

Comment: When you get to your computer, upload the rest of your relevant code

Comment: Added rest of the code; will check the removal of the parenthesis later on my coworkers computer.